# Using ember data how can I fetch children async individually?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

The use case is quite simple, but I seem to be missing something.

This is my first real crack at ember, and the use case is strange... but any assistance would be welcome.

My store looks like this:

```
App.TroubleTicket = DS.Model.extend({
     'name'        : DS.attr('string'),
     'type'        : DS.attr('string'),
     'resolutions' : DS.hasMany('resolution', async : true);
});

App.Resolution = DS.Model.extend({
    'troubleTicket' : DS.belongsTo('troubleTicket', async : true);
    'description' : DS.attr('string');
});
```

The payload for the first is:

```
{
    "troubleTicket" : {
        "id"   : "TICKET-123",
        "type" : "Issue",
        "resolutions" : ["RES-123", "RES-321", "RES-213"]
     }
}
```

I get this payload just fine, however the expected behavior of this setup is that each of the resolutions is its own HTTP GET when rendering.

When this resource is requested, a get with query params is executed by JQuery, however the desired behavior is a new http.get for each of the resolution ids.

Any direction would be wonderful.

Comment: What version of ember-data are you using? That was changed to the default behavior in [Beta-9](http://emberjs.com/blog/2014/08/18/ember-data-1-0-beta-9-released.html). See the section on HasMany Coalescing Now Opt-In.

Comment: You know tahts a good question, used the ember generator. one sec

Comment: using beta 8 let me try the upgrade real quick.

Comment: @NicholasJohn16 upgrading was the correct solution. Can you post an answer so I can give you credit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please upgrade your version of Ember-data.  That feature was made default in [Beta-9](http://emberjs.com/blog/2014/08/18/ember-data-1-0-beta-9-released.html#toc_hasmany-coalescing-now-opt-in).